# iPhone SDK - UIScrollView & UIPageControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I created a UIScrollView / UIPageControl .xib scrolling between 12 images. At the bottom of the .xib is a "Submit" button that would save the value of the scroll view in a web service.

How can I get the "submit" button to grab that value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIScrollView has three properties: contentOffset, contentInset, and the contentSize that define the user's scroll state.

The offset in particular is likely what you what to send to your web service.